# Jmeter- How to Extract part of the API Response value using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have the below response from the API:

```
{"info":{"message":"success","details":{}},"data":"https://127.0.0.1:80/view-report?https://routethis.creativeadvtech.ml/api/v1/report/get_subscriber_report?verification_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ2aWV3X3JlcG9ydF90b2tlbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0NDQyNzEzNSwibmJmIjoxNjQ0NDI3MTM1LCJqdGkiOiJhOTFlZWY0Ny01ZWY1LTQ3YWEtYTc0Ny1mYTNhOWM4MWRmNjMiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJyZXBvcnRfaWQiOiI1YzQxYzU4MC04OWNjLTExZWMtOWM4Zi1hNjkzNGQ4NWQxMDkiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6ImY2MGIyMjc0LWQ2MTAtNDBkMS1iNjJjLTc5NTEwOWZjMjk0ZiJ9.ica2CS-cT3RxbNPhMUn1Tw_HGtODmgAzS_JpjoS22NU"}
```

**Question:**
How to extract the Verification_token value only notice that the whole data response is a full value attached to each other?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression extracts the whole contents of `data` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), why would you expect it to return the partial value.

If you need the token only - you need to amend your regular expression to something like:

```
{"info":{"message":"success","details":{}},"data":".*verification_token=(.+?)"}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thank you soo much , it works :D